# Ansible = use facts as variables in inventory file

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

I'm using Ansible to install and configure Red Hat OpenShift. One of the challenges I'm currently facing is with setting up LDAP auth using a playbook. I need to add the following variable to the Ansible inventory file -

**LDAP auth**

> openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'idm-ldap', 'challenge': 'true', 'login': 'true', 'kind': 'LDAPPasswordIdentityProvider', 'attributes': {'id': ['dn'], 'email': ['mail'], 'name': ['cn'], 'preferredUsername': ['uid']}, 'bindDN': '"uid=<...>-bind,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=<...>-01-<...>,dc=svcs,dc=<...>,dc=com"', 'bindPassword': {'file': '/etc/origin/master/artifacts/<...>.encrypted', 'keyFile': '/etc/origin/master/artifacts/<...>.key'}, 'ca': '/etc/origin/master/artifacts/<...>.crt', 'insecure': 'false', 'url': '"ldaps://<...>.<...>-<...>-<...>.<...>.<...>.com:<...>/ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?uid"'}]*

As this playbook is going to be used across different environments, I'd really like to be able to use the current hostname fact of the ansible host at playbook runtime as a variable to substitute for the value of `url': '"ldaps://etc"`.

Is this possible? I've done a lot of searching but can't find any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a variable inside of a variable string using jinja2 the same as you do inside playbooks and task files (using double curly braces inside of double quotes):

INI:

```
myvar="{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
```

YAML:

```
---
myvar: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
```

Applied specifically to your example:

```
openshift_master_identity_providers="[{'name': 'idm-ldap', 'challenge': 'true', 'login': 'true', 'kind': 'LDAPPasswordIdentityProvider', 'attributes': {'id': ['dn'], 'email': ['mail'], 'name': ['cn'], 'preferredUsername': ['uid']}, 'bindDN': '"uid=-bind,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=-01-,dc=svcs,dc=,dc=com"', 'bindPassword': {'file': '/etc/origin/master/artifacts/.encrypted', 'keyFile': '/etc/origin/master/artifacts/.key'}, 'ca': '/etc/origin/master/artifacts/.crt', 'insecure': 'false', 'url': 'ldaps://{{ ansible_fqdn }}:/ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?uid'}]"
```

Note that the entire variable value has double quotes around it. I'm assuming this is the intended behavior, otherwise you would be better off using YAML to build out a more complex dictionary.